# Is it possible to stop reading a byte before the end of file -1

Tags: java

I am just a month into programming with java, please I need some assistance. I have a Client-Server Socket application. I only have control over the client side so I am reading from an BufferedInputStream but the problem is I need to only read the XML and ignore the end of Stream character/Integer 255. The current output comes with � in the console. Is it possible for me to ignore this last character when reading incoming data?.

**Below is my code:**

```
//Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss");

            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

             while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                 result.write(buffer, 0, length);
             String loginResponse = result.toString();
             System.out.println(formatter.format(System.currentTimeMillis())+ " " +loginResponse + "  \n");
```

Comment: What do you think would come after the last character?

Comment: 255 is what is at the end of the XML. For example the Socket Server is sending the XML string <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><cookie VALUE='default'/>255. 

I would like to only read the XML part of the incoming response without the appended 255. Please help!!

Comment: Then add `if (buffer[length - 1] == 255) length--;` inside the loop, before the `write()` call.

Comment: Thanks Andrewa, I added 

if (buffer[length - 1] == 255) length--; 

but I am still getting the character at the end of the XML

Comment: @Andreas That should be `(byte)255`, or `-1`, not `255`, which will never match a byte, but all this is attacking the problem at the wrong end.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. The error is at the server. Fix that. It should not transmit the 255.

Or maybe there is no real problem to solve, only a display issue. If you feed that XML to any properly written XML parser, it will stop at the closing `/>` and ignore anything after it,

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your help. I eventually managed to do it with the code below. The Client server application are running now on productions. Many thanks for all your help.

```
//Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss");

            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

             while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                 if (buffer[length - 1] == 255) length--;
                 result.write(buffer, 0, length);
             String loginResponse = result.toString();

             //Remove last appended Octet
            String ussdmsg = loginResponse.substring(0, loginResponse.length() - 1);


             System.out.println(formatter.format(System.currentTimeMillis())+ " " +ussdmsg + "  \n");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like following:

```
while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
  if (length>=3) {
    if ((buffer[length-1] == '5') && (buffer[length-2] == '5') && (buffer[length-3] == '2')) {
      buffer[length-3] = '\0';
      buffer[length-2] = '\0';
      buffer[length-1] = '\0';
      length -=3;
    }
  }
result.write(buffer, 0, length);

String loginResponse = result.toString();
System.out.println(formatter.format(System.currentTimeMillis())+ " " +loginResponse + "  \n");
}
```

Comment: The question clearly states that it is a single character and even shows how it is printed.

Comment: If input is: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><cookie VALUE='default'/>255 then it is obviously not a single character.

Comment: Read the question. The OP *clearly states* both '*the* end of stream character' and 'this last character', and she also posts what it looks like, which is one glyph. Not three, and not `255`. Clearly the 255 is a character *value*.

Comment: Thank you all, I will try each of your suggestions and share status update as soon as I can. I sincerely appreciate your help, Thanks